# Missing required argument $mainTable on Collection

Tags: collection, grid, magento2.3.4

I have a custom grid, where it gets some data from the shipment table.
This is the error message received:

```
Missing required argument $mainTable of Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection.
```

This is the code from di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendor_module_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

and my `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection` file:

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection as ShipmentGridCollection;
class Collection extends ShipmentGridCollection
{
    /**
     * @var ShipmentHelper
     */
    private $shipmentHelper;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        Logger $logger, FetchStrategy
        $fetchStrategy,
        EventManager $eventManager,
        $mainTable = 'sales_shipment_grid',
        $resourceModel = Shipment::class,
        ShipmentHelper $shipmentHelper
    ) {
        $this->shipmentHelper = $shipmentHelper;
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory,
            $logger,
            $fetchStrategy,
            $eventManager,
            $mainTable,
            $resourceModel
        );
    }
    /**
     * Filter the sales_order_grid table
     */
    protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
    {
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['sales_shipment' => $this->getTable('sales_shipment')],
            'main_table.increment_id = sales_shipment.increment_id',
            ['sales_shipment.entity_id as shipment_entity_id']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->join(
            ['sales_order' => $this->getTable('sales_order')],
            'sales_shipment.order_id = sales_order.entity_id',
            ['status']
        );
        $this->getSelect()->order('main_table.entity_id ASC');
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }

}
```

Does anyone know why exactly I got that error ? Thank you

Comment: please share complete code of yours di.xml file in above question.

Comment: @HiteshBalpande that is all of it, except the <config> tag

Answer (score 3):

Change di.xml file

```
 <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Grid\Collection">
<arguments>
    <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sales_shipment_grid</argument>
    <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal</argument>
</arguments>
```

Answer (score 1):

> please try to change your di.xml code with below one.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="vendor_module_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    
    <type name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Order\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">your_main_table_name</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module__grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Order</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```